# How can I do a loop foreach in asynchronous methode with signalR in .NET Core?`

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, signalr

In my case I want to send the message to all sessions not only user (user can have many sessions), I used foreach to send message to all connections belong to friends with its others sessions,
there is a problem in `await` asynchronous and a message:

> Failed writing message. Aborting connection.    System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOption

```
// Test if the user is offline :
// Find My opened sessions and target opened sessions
if (userInfoReciever != null)
{
    var targetSessions = _context.Connections.Where(C => (C.Username == targetUserModel.UserName) && (C.Connected == true)).ToList();

    if (targetSessions != null)
    { 
        foreach (var targetSeesion in targetSessions)
        {
            await Clients.Client(targetSeesion.ConnectionID).SendAsync("SendDM", messageModel, userInfoSender);
            await Clients.Client(targetSeesion.ConnectionID).SendAsync("SendDN", notificationModel, userInfoSender);
        }
    }
}

await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("MyMessage", messageModel, userInfoSender);

if (userInfoSender != null)
{
    var mySessions = _context.Connections.Where(C => ((C.ConnectionID != Context.ConnectionId) && (C.Username == Context.User.Identity.Name) && (C.Connected == true))).ToList();

    if (mySessions != null) 
    {
        foreach(var mySession in mySessions)
        {
            await Clients.Client(mySession.ConnectionID).SendAsync("MyMessage", messageModel, userInfoSender);
        }
    }
}

// Send my message to the the others sessions :

// Build the message
var _message = _mapper.Map<MessageViewModel,Message>(messageModel);
var _notification = _mapper.Map<NotificationViewModel, Notification>(notificationModel);
await _context.Messages.AddAsync(_message);
await _context.Notifications.AddAsync(_notification);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Check your version of Json. You may be referencing an older version instead of core

Comment: How can i change it , it was working before i added the foreach

Comment: You can change it in nuget or in your cproj file depending on your asp version. You also should lock your mySessions or create a lock because the signalr hub is a singleton.

Comment: can you help me more by an example in my code to lock mysession variable, and thank you

Comment: Look into SemaphoreSlim. Create a new static global instance (private static readonly SemaphoreSlim lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1)). Then just await the lock and do your processing (await lock.WaitAsync(); try { foreach (var mySession in mySessions) { await Clients.Client(mySession.ConnectionID).SendAsync("MyMessage", messageModel, userInfoSender): } } finally { lock.Release(); }